# Sum of two open sets is open?

Tags: general-topology, sumset

how to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are open in $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ then  $A+B$ is open ?

Where   $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$

Thank you

Comment: What a terrible use of the first comma in the definition of $A+B$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The continuous linear map $T((x,y)) = x+y$ is surjective, hence an open map. Since $A \times B$ is open, we see that $T(A \times B)$ is open.

Comment: I think the OP may not be familiar with things like the product topology, and the fact that the projection map $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an open map.  Nevertheless this is a very slick answer

Comment: @D_S: I'm in a one liner (OK, maybe 1.5 liner) mood today :-).

Comment: @copper.hat T is defined from $A\times B$ to $A+B$ right ? any surjective map is open ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I think the other answers are more appropriate than mine. Any continuous, surjective linear map between Banach spaces is an open map (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29).

Answer (score 16):

**Hint:**
$$A+B = \bigcup_{a\in A}(a+B).$$

Comment: why $\{a\}+B$ is open please

Comment: @Vrouvrou Try using the definition of open set you have.

Comment: @Vrouvrou because $\{x: |x|<r\}+\{a\}=\{x:|x-a|<r\}$

Comment: a set is open if it is a neighborhood of all it's point or if it is the preimage of an open set with a continuous function

Comment: @Vrouvrou You can prove it using the first definition directly (triangular inequality...) or with the second one (translations...)

Comment: @TZakrevskiy why |x-a| nd not |x+a| ?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud how by triangular inequality ?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud if i let $z\in A+B$ then there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $a+b=z$, What is the open U such that $z\in U\subset A+B$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I'm not here to do your homework for you. Try to work on it a bit, draw some pictures, and when you'll have an answer try to post it and I'll be happy to give you feedback.

Comment: @Vrouvrou because you shift a ball centered in zero of radius $r$ by a vector $a$. You obtain a ball of radius $r$ centered in the point $a$, hence the $|x-a|<r$.

Comment: Why delete it?   He got 50 reputation points from it lol and it's a good answer.  Anyway, why don't you ask a new question: "if $B$ is open, why is $a+B$ also open?"

Comment: Where have we used that A is open?

Comment: @Gitika We haven't (and we don't need to).

Comment: Oh okay..so we can just say that sum of open set and any other arbitrary set is open..right?

Comment: @Gitika Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is an open set, and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, let's show that $a + B = \{a + b : b \in B\}$ is also open.

What do open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ look like?  They are unions of open intervals.  That is, there exist numbers $a_i, b_i$ etc. such that $$B = \bigcup\limits_i (a_i,b_i)$$ Now, it should be obvious that $a + (a_i,b_i) = (a+a_i,a+ b_i)$, which is open.  You can then argue that $$a+B = \bigcup\limits_i (a+a_i,a+b_i)$$ so $a+B$ is a union of open sets.